# zsh: command not found: express - express-generator version 4.2.0 installed

Tags: node.js, express, oh-my-zsh

whenever I try to use the express command I get `zsh: command not found: express`

When I run `npm info express version` I get `4.4.5` and when I run `info express-generator version` I get `4.2.0`

The answer to this question normally is to install `express-generator` or `express-generator@3` but I've already done that and it's still not working

Answer (score 2):

Did you install `express-generator` ***globally*** (`npm install -g express-generator`)?